# javascript possible to use polygon[i].x instead of polygon[i][j]?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, user-defined-types

I'm struggling with this concept. Is is possible in javascript to create a user defined so I can use

```
polygon[i].x
polygon[i].y
```

instead of

```
polygon[i][0]
polygon[i][1]
```

The code for polygon[i][j] is below.

```
var polygon = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    polygon[i] = new Array(2);
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        polygon[i][j] = "[" + i + "," + j + "]";
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++)
{
    alert(polygon[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: In JS, `blah.x` is equivalent to `blah['x']`.

Comment: look into plain objects and object literals

Comment: @Barmar note that `polygon[i]` is an array. It shouldn't be if you do this.

Comment: Learn more about objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand your code, this would be it:

```
var polygon = [],
    i;

//push an object with x and y into the polygon array
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  polygon.push({
    x : 'x @'+i,
    y : 'y @'+i
  });
}

//accessible as
polygon[index].x
polygon[index].y
```